# Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed : ADODB

Tags: vbscript

I am using ADO to connect to EXCEL from 64bit machine by VBScript. The MS Office(2013) is 32bit.
The connection string is

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
objExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & myXlsFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;" & strHeader & """"
```

And it shows an error: **Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed** 
error code:**800A0E7A**

Please help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just look to your right you will see the **Related** list of questions, this question has been answered so many times but OPs don't approve the answer so can't mark this as a duplicate, there are at least two directly related to ACE and 10 altogether about the same subject matter. The likelihood is you are trying to access the 64 Bit provider of ACE where only the 32 Bit one is installed regardless of the OS architecture you should be using `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` versions of `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe` to execute the script and access the 32 bit registry to get the correct provider version

Answer (score -2):

kindly refer this tutorial how to use ADO to read and write data in Excel workbooks

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278973
https://quicktestprofessional.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/adodb-connection-to-read-data-from-excel-sheet/

Comment: The issue is bitness architecture *(x86 vs x64)*, this answer is pointless and off the mark.

Comment: I already tried those. But doesn't work in my machine

Comment: @DON They won't a lot of them are ancient when CPU architecture was solely 32 bit. Wouldn't recommend any of them now. That support article is copyright 16 years ago.